# Return value From Fucntion to Traits GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, enthought, traits

I am trying to develop a GUI using Enthought.  I'm a little confused as to how to use Traits and return a value from a function to be displayed on the GUI.  Below I wrote a simple GUI displaying my problems.

```
    from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, String, Float, Enum, Button, Str, List, Bool, Int
    from traitsui.api import Handler, View, Item, Group, HSplit, NoButtons, VGroup, VGrid, HGroup, EnumEditor, Action, ProgressEditor, ButtonEditor
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    import simple_GUI_function

     class Input_Panel(HasTraits):

        Name = Str(name='Name', label="Name")
        Iterations = Str(name='Iterations',label="Iterations")

        #~ #Create the User Information panel
        User_Information_Panel = View(VGroup(
                                             VGrid(
                                                   Item('Name'), 
                                                   Item('Iterations'), 
                                                   ),
                                              show_border=True, label="Information"
                                            )
                                      )

        class Output_Panel(HasTraits):

             counter_out = Int(0)

             User_Output_Panel = View(VGrid(
                                             Item('counter_out', width=-10, style='readonly',resizable=False                    
                                                 ),
                                           )
                                      )



             class Program_Execute_Thread(Handler):

                  wants_abort = False

                  pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)


                 def process(self, iterations):
                      try:
                          if self.processing_job.isAlive():
                          return
                      except AttributeError:
                          pass
                      self.processing_job = Thread(target = process, args = (iterations))
                      self.processing_job.start()

                 def run(self):

                      while not self.wants_abort:

                           print("here")


                            async_result = pool.apply_async(simple_GUI_function.Gui_func.Func_test(simple_GUI_function.Gui_func(), iterations))

                            return_val = async_result.get()




              class Start_Panel(HasTraits):

                   Program_Execute = Instance(Program_Execute_Thread)


                   Start_Button = Button(name = 'Start', action='_Start_Button', tooltip = 'Start')    
                   Quit_Button = Button(name = 'Exit Program', action='_Quit_Button', tooltip = 'Quit')

                   Button_Panel = View(HGroup(
                                              Item('Start_Button', show_label = False),
                                              Item('Quit_Button', show_label = False),
                                              )
                                      )


                  def _Start_Button_fired(self):

                       if self.Program_Execute and self.Program_Execute.isAlive():
                           self.Program_Execute.wants_abort = True
                       else:
                           self.Program_Execute = Program_Execute_Thread()
                           self.Program_Execute.start()

                       print("Start Button pushed")


                 def _Quit_Button_fired(self):

                       print("Quit Button pushed")



              class MainWindowHandler(Handler):

                    def close(self, info, is_OK):


                    #~ if (info.object.button_panel.Program_Execute_Thread and \
                    #~ info.object.button_panel.Program_Execute_Thread.isAlive()):
                    #~ info.object.button_panel.Program_Execute_Thread.wants_abort = True
                    #~ while info.object.Program_Execute_Thread.isAlive():
                    #~ sleep(0.1)
                    #~ GUI.process_events()

                        return True


              class MainWindow(HasTraits):

                    user_input = Instance(Input_Panel, ())
                    user_output = Instance(Output_Panel, ())
                    button_panel = Instance(Start_Panel, ())


                    view = View(VGroup(Item('user_input', style = 'custom', show_label = False), 
                                       Item('user_output', style = 'custom', show_label = False),
                                       Item('button_panel', style = 'custom', show_label = False),
                                       show_labels = False),
                                       resizable = True, handler = MainWindowHandler(),
                                )



              if __name__ == '__main__':
                   MainWindow().configure_traits()
```

Here is the simple function the code is trying to call:

```
    class Gui_func:


         def Func_test(self, iteration):

             import time

             print("Inside the function")

             time.sleep(2)

             print("Now leaving the function")

             p = iteration + 1

             return p
```

The code will register the Start button begin pushed but keeps generating the error "Program_Execute_Thread" object has no attribute 'start'.  I looked at the Camera.py threading example built using Traits and built my code around that example.  It seems like Python is not recognizing my Program_Execute_Thread as a "Thread."  Anybody have any ideas?

Cheers,
Shivels

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem.  Looks like I forgot to declare Program_Execute_Thread as "Program_Execute_Thread(Thread)"  and also I had to start the thread.